# CSS property 'resize' doesn't work with 'sticky'

Tags: css, sass

I've created a grid-based table replacement.

The grid is meant to keep table headers on the top when scrolling, for that I've utilized `position: sticky;`.

While it works flawlessly, it doesn't seem to care if I set `resize: horizontal;` on it, it just won't let me - I can have either, but not both.

Is there a workaround? Sorry if I don't post the HTML code, it's generated by vue and it's rather unreadable, plus I would have to post vue component contents.

Here's SASS thought:

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnCount), minmax(min-content, 1fr));
  max-height: 100px;
}

.table-headers {
  display: contents;
  top: 0;
}

.table-headers > .table-header:last-of-type > .table-header-resizer {
  display: none;
}

.table-header {
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-right: 1px solid #D5E3EA;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D5E3EA;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.table-header:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

.table-header-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  resize: horizontal;
  padding: 8px;
}

.table-row {
  display: contents;
}

.table-row > .table-cell {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-top: 1px solid #D5E3EA;
}

.table-row > .table-cell:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.table-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid #D5E3EA;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-cell:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style='--columnCount: 3;'>
<div class="table-headers">
    <div class="table-header">
        <div class="table-cell">
            One
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-header">
        <div class="table-cell">
            Two
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-header">
        <div class="table-cell">
            Three
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        Three
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we get a fiddle/snippet, please?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález It's generated by vuejs, but sure... it'll be barelly readable thought.

Comment: You have to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not your hundred-lines code pasted here, but a minimal example showing the problem. You need to show effort in your questions if you want to receive something back, of course. This is also JavaScript so you better use jsfiddle or the internal snippet tool. There's info about that on the link I've passed. You are an active answerer. I bet you prefer to see the problem rapidly instead of fiddling around lots of non-relevant lines haha.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Js has nothing to do with it. The issue is that `resize` and `position: sticky;` can't both exist on the same dom element for some reason. BTW I'm cleaning the code as we speak ^^

Comment: Oh yeah, a JavaScript/CSS/HTTML mix. Everything fits the snippet tool (sorry, I'm used to say JavaScript when talking about the snippet tool, but it works for any mix of all 3, just take a look to it). For example, I only have some spare minutes, and I saw your question. I saw all the work I need to do to have a minimal reproducible example (which I have to work to reach it), so I'm not wasting time on this question. If you already give the minimal reproducible example, I'm pretty sure I would answer rapidly. To making it easy to your helpers, is better for you actually.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I hope the example I've provided is satisfactory.

Comment: Way better ^^ Let's see...

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I've... just solved the problem lol.

Comment: Hahahahaha. That's perfect! You cannot imagine the times I was going to ask to StackOverflow and while I was writting the question and doing the reproducible example found the problem.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Happened to me before too. Oh, well. Hope somebody stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same issue, simply put a nested child inside your sticky element and set resize on it instead.